# Using Proc SQL to join two datasets with 2 matching variables

Tags: sql, join, sas

I have two datasets A & B. I want to join them against two fields: ID and End of Month date. This is defined as EOMDate in dataset A and BalDate in dataset B. How do I join them so that ID and the dates match with each other?

Comment: `a.id=b.id and a.eomdate=b.baldate`  What did you try? Can you post a few sample rows from each and what you want as output?

Answer (score 0):

Tom's comment works. Here are a few worked samples:

```
/*Create some input data for the samples...*/
data first; 
    input id_a id_b data $;
    cards;
    1 1 A
    2 2 B
    3 33 C  
    4 4 D
    55 5 E
;
run;

data second; 
    input id_a id_b data2 $;
    cards;
    1 1 AA
    2 2 BB
    3 3 CC 
    4 4 DD
    5 5 EE
;
run;

/*The proc sql way. We create table 'combo' as result. */
/*You can add more conditions than one. */

proc sql noprint;
    create table combo as 
    select * from first join second
    on first.id_a=second.id_a and first.Id_b=second.id_b;
quit;
```

I've noticed that proc sql is quite slow when working with large sets.
This is a way to make the same with data statements.
First you need to sort the data.

```
/*A way to accomplish this with datasets.*/
proc sort data=first; by id_a id_b; run;
proc sort data=second; by id_a id_b; run;

data Combo_sas;
    merge first(in=a) second(in=b); 
    by id_a id_b; 
    if a and b;
run;
```